# ES cluster QPS stats when splitting index documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When using `org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient#search`, are the QPS stats the same for ES clusters when specifying to query multiple indexes, as opposed to querying a single index?

Recently, we split the index data of the Elasticsearch cluster, which improves the performance a lot, but the QPS of the Elasticsearch cluster is increased by about 10 times.

In addition, the write TPS of the cluster does not change much before and after the index data is split.